# Wordpress meta query with multiple key value pairs and relations

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I have the following problem.
On my WordPress page there are small sticky posts and one big sticky post, this is all fine. But there are also regular posts and I need to not display the posts that are marked as sticky or big sticky with a meta value.

I need to query for value is not true or doesn't exist for `home_post` key and value is not true or doesn't exist for `big_home_post` key.

The code I came up with is the following:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'big_home_post',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
         array(
            'key' => 'big_home_post',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'home_post',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
         array(
            'key' => 'home_post',
            'value' => true,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
),
```

The code is not working.

Maybe the multidimensional array is not built correctly or WordPress doesn't support this at all.

All help is appreciated

Comment: In your example you are using `big_home_post` and `home_post` ?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, i copied the example from my source and wrote the comment out of my head. Didn't memorize as well as i thought.

Comment: So the original one is `home_post` and `big_home_post` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hüseyin BABAL's answer is outdated. As codex states:

> Starting with version 4.1, meta_query clauses can be nested in order to construct complex queries.

So `meta_query` value like in question would work.

[Codex: Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to use nested array in meta_query. You need to write your own query for that. I suggest you to following code to achieve your target;

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'custom_meta_query_enabled' => true,
) );

add_filter( 'posts_join', 'custom_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_meta_query( $join, $query ) {
    if ( empty( $query->query_vars['custom_meta_query_enabled'] ) )
        return $join;

    global $wpdb;
    $new_join = "
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} wppm ON 1=1
            AND wppm.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.ID
            AND (wppm.meta_key != 'big_home_post' OR (wppm.meta_key = 'big_home_post' AND wppm.meta_value != true)
            AND (wppm.meta_key != 'home_post' OR (wppm.meta_key = 'home_post' AND wppm.meta_value != true)
    ";
    return $join . ' ' . $new_join;
}
```

Simply, I have put a control called `custom_meta_query_enabled`. If you set this field in your `WP_Query` to true, system query will be overrided with custom join query. In order to use this, you can put it in `functions.php`

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked flawless!